# How can I scroll content of <webview> tag from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

- atom-shell: https://github.com/atom/atom-shell
- version: v0.20.2

I am using `<webview>` tag to embed a page. `<webview>` tag has `shadow-root` which has one tag, `<object id="browser-plugin-1 ...>`. So I tried to set `scrollTop` value for this tag like this.

```
var webView = document.getElementById('webview tag id');
var elm = webView.shadowRoot.firstChild; // elm is object tag
console.log(elm.scrollTop);  // 0
elm.scrollTop = 100;
console.log(elm.scrollTop);  // 0
```

But nothing happend...
Is it possible to control `<webview>` tag scroll position from outside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, do this instead:

```
var webView = document.getElementById('webview tag id');
webView.executeJavaScript("document.querySelector('body:first-child').scrollTop=100");
```

Comment: Thanks, @paul. I could control like this `webView.executeJavaScript("document.querySelector('body').scrollTop=100;");`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to execute any kind of javascript via the `WebView.executeJavaScript(code)` function which will evaluate the code inside the WebView.

To access your element you would first have to wait for the WebView to load, and then execute the javascript.

```
var webView = document.getElementById('webView');
webView.addEventListener('did-finish-load', scrollElement );

function scrollElement(){
    var code = "var elm = document.querySelector('body:first-child'); elm.scrollTop = 100;";
    webView.executeJavaScript(code);
}
```

**Note**: Haven't tested this code, it may have syntax errors.

[Source (AtomShell's WebView tag documentation)](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md)